# App crash when add react-native-firebase/admob

Tags: react-native, crash, admob, react-native-firebase

How to add react-native-firebase admob to react native ("0.60.x"). App crash when adding admob. Are there any other option to add admob to react-native app. react-native-admob also the same crashing problem.

Comment: Can you put the error you got? Also crash on android or iOS?

Comment: Android. 

I managed the issue. But when I add the react navigation to the project error comes again.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:

Comment: Can try by cleaning the project with `cd android && ./gradlew clean` and try to run agian

Answer (score 6):

Within the root of your React Native project, create a **firebase.json** file (if it doesn't already exist) and add the admob_android_app_id & admob_ios_app_id keys with the IDs from the Google AdMob console:

Like:

```
{
  "react-native": {
    "admob_android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx",
    "admob_ios_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```